# How to eject iso based dvd drive on Windows

Tags: python, windows, iso

I'm trying to make a code that will eject the dvd drive created when an iso file is opened on windows 10. I would prefer it based on the name of the iso file, but I can also use drive letter if necessary. Below is the code for the creation of the iso file.

```
import pycdlib

def make_iso(name):
    iso = pycdlib.PyCdlib()
    iso.new()
    iso.write(f'{name}.iso')
    iso.close()
```

Now I want to make `def eject_iso` so that it ejects an the iso when called. Any ideas?

Comment: What tool did you use to mount the ISO?

Comment: @TimRoberts I used `os.startfile(f"{name}.iso")`

Comment: What exactly does eject mean on a file?

Comment: @MarkRansom an iso file is loaded as a DVD drive. Eject here means the same as ejecting a DVD, only without a physical form.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows command `mountvol` can do this:

```
mountvol D: /d
```

You can do that via `subprocess.call` or `os.system`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that you can use to eject the DVD drive created when an ISO file is opened on Windows 10:

```
import pycdlib
import os

def make_iso(name):
    iso = pycdlib.PyCdlib()
    iso.new()
    iso.write(f'{name}.iso')
    iso.close()

def eject_iso(name):
    drive_letter = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + ':\\'
    try:
        os.system(f'Eject {drive_letter}')
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_iso('my_iso')
    eject_iso('my_iso')
```